# Error de Desboradimiento en Visual Basic al exportar una datagridview a Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hola tengo la siguiente funcion en visual basic que lo hace es recibir los datos de entrada para exportar los datos de una datagrid view hacia un archivo excel, el problema se produce a la hora de hacer la ejecucion de la funcion, me sale el error de la imagen, alguien que diga que estoy haciendo mal o que debo corregir:

Public Sub crearLibroExcelRS(rs As ADODB.Recordset, appHoja As String)
On Error GoTo conErr

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim y As Long
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(2)
    xlSheet.Delete
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(2)
    xlSheet.Delete
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
     
    xlApp.Visible = False
    
    xlSheet.Name = appHoja
    
    n = 1
    
    y = 1
    
    For i = 0 To (rs.Fields.Count - 1)
        xlSheet.Cells(y, n).Value = (UCase(rs.Fields(i).Name))
        n = n + 1
    Next
    
    y = 2
    
    Dim nreg As Integer
    nreg = rs.RecordCount
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        n = 1
      
        For i = 0 To (rs.Fields.Count - 1)
            xlSheet.Cells(y, n).Value = IIf(IsNull(rs.Fields(i)), "SIN DATOS", IIf(IsDate(rs.Fields(i)), Format(rs.Fields(i), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"), RTrim(LTrim(rs.Fields(i)))))
      
            n = n + 1
        Next
        
        y = y + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    xlApp.Visible = True
    
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
conErr:
    
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    MsgBox err.Description
    
    Call msgError(err, " - Exportar a Excel")
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿qué línea de código levanta el error? ¿Lo has debugeado con F8 línea a línea?

Comment: la verdad no se donde se produce el error es el error que me da el msgerror al terminar de ejecutar la funcion

Comment: desde la linea "nreg = rs.RecordCount" salta directamente al conErr

Comment: Tienes definido `nreg` como `Integer` cuyo límite máximo es en torno a 32.000. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary si hay más de 32.000 registros, se produce un desbordamiento. Prueba a definirlo de tipo `Long`

Comment: hola, gracias, si ese era un inconveniente que tenia